# Website resolves to local address using apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, ubuntu, proxy, reverse

I have set up a reverse proxy with apache and am pointing to 4 other apache wordpress server vm's on my local network.

When I go to the websites on 3 of them (like www.mywebsite.com externally from my computer at work), they resolve fine and the sites produce the page correctly.

When I try to connect to the 4th site, it redirects me to a 192 address which is what I have in the proxy config but it does not resolve correctly like the other sites. I literally copy and pasted each block in the 000-default.conf so I know they are identical.

The proxy works and is moving the traffic but will try to resolve locally. Here is the block from my 000-default.conf.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
# the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
# redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
# specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
# match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
# value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
# However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

ServerName www.mywebsite.com

ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.23:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.23:80/

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Im not sure what is different between the sites. Ive done this quite a few times and never had the issue. Could this be an issue with the web server on the 4th site? These are all VM's running ubuntu server with lamp.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was an issue with the 4th server and how it was handling the index file with wordpress. It seems that Wordpress had to be provisioned locally first. But, I dont remember doing this with the other sites. All is well now.